# MySQL Workbench has stopped working while conecting to My Localhost Server

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I started the MySQL database via XAMPP and try to use MySQL Workbench to connect to the database server. MySQL Workbench stopped working after I click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button to connect.

```
MySQL Workbench Version: 6.3.7 build 1199 CE (64 bits)
```

Connection Information
[image]

Error Message
[image]

XAMPP Information
[image]

Even if I use <kbd>Forward Engineer to Database</kbd>, it shows me `Operation has completed with errors. Please see logs for details.`. The Message Log is shown in the following.

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `codespace`.`terminalpreferences` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `CodeSpace`.`TerminalPreferences`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CodeSpace`.`TerminalPreferences` (
          `id` INT ZEROFILL UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `acePreferenceId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
          UNIQUE INDEX `acePreferenceId_UNIQUE` (`acePreferenceId` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `acePreferenceId`
            FOREIGN KEY (`acePreferenceId`)
            REFERENCES `CodeSpace`.`ACEPreferences` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Could not get definition for CodeSpace.All_User from server
1 views were read back.
```

[image]

Is these means that if I haven't set up the database properly, I cannot connect to it? Or, this is a bug?

#### UPDATE

After I solved all the error in my database design and successfully forward the engineer to database. The connection problem still not solved.

Comment: for me using workbench is a love/hate experience. It crashes a lot. Especially after I start typing the colon in things like `set @x1:= ...` , so sometimes I rem out the line with `-- ` first, type it, then un-rem. As if. Then other times it is fine for days. Point being, it is flakey as all get up.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200130/mysql-workbench-crashing-when-connecting